# Is there a good design/architecture pattern to use for building a mobile to server syncing feature?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

I have a IOS and Android mobile app that has some photos/videos of varying sizes that need to be backed up to a backend for storage.

In the simplest sense, I am thinking that the app will back up new files one by one to a cloud storage service like Google Cloud Storage or Amazon S3. If it fails on uploading any one file, it will need to reupload that whole file again.

Are there any better design/architecture patterns to more efficiently upload the files to the cloud storage? Having a resume upload feature will be cool, but sounds complicated to implement on both the app side and backend side.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

AWS S3 has proven highly successful for me for very similar purposes. I've built apps used by tens of thousands of users each of which upload files upwards of a few GB in size. S3 multipart upload is a savior when it comes to reliability when uploading large files -

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/s3transfermanager.html#multipart-upload

Comment: That's interesting for the multipart upload feature for S3, thanks for sharing. Does Google Cloud Storage or the other cloud platforms not have this ability too?

Comment: Yes but I have no experience with it and to be clear, I wasn't saying others didn't have this option but more so that it hasn't failed me, yet. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/multipart-upload

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/). It is built to simplify mobile developer life so they can stop to worry about resumable uploads, etc. and focus on their app.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud storage services like AWS S3 and Google Cloud Storage do have support for upload resume in case of errors. Look into their APIs.

If you are looking for an easy way to upload files to a cloud storage, an API integration SDK like [CloudRail](https://cloudrail.com) can be a good choice. It has support for AWS S3, Google Cloud Storage, Microsoft Azure etc.